# Update Angular to latest

Tags: angular, angular-material

There has been a few modifications with the Angular-Material. Now the date-picker and other feature are added. How to update project so as to have the latest version of angular. 
I tried to update but I am having these errors

```
Class 'MdOptgroup' incorrectly implements interface 'Can
Disable'.
Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MdOptgroup'.

node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'Renderer2'.

Class 'MdTab' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'.Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MdTab'.


Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeofMdTabLabelWrapperBase' is not a constructor function type.

Class 'MdToolbar' incorrectly implements interface 'CanColor'.
Property 'color' is missing in type 'MdToolbar'.

ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'InjectionToken', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a refe
rence to an exported function, resolving symbol MATERIAL_SANITY_CHECKS in /node_modules/@angular/material/typings/index.d.ts, resolving symbol MdCommonModule in node_modules/@angular/material/typings/index.d.ts, resolving symbol MdCommonModule in /node_modules/@angular/material/typings/index.d.ts
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Peruse the migration guide and see what code of yours has suffered under certain breaking API changes?

Comment: I have searched for migration guide ( I mean for the latest changes in late May or early June), but I haven't found any.

Comment: I added more errors. So my guess is that most of the errors are due to @angular/material module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the latest version of Angular in a project you will need to update your global angular and the angular inside your project. I am hard coding the latest version numbers from 2017/6/24:

`npm update -g "@angular/cli@1.1.3` to update global.

and inside the project directory:

`npm update "@angular/cli@1.1.3` to update the project.

Then upgrade Angular Material in the project:

`npm update "@angular/material@2.0.0-beta.7`

You may find `npm outdated` and `npm update` useful to find other packages that need updating.

This answers the question "How to update project so as to have the latest version of angular". I have yet to see the errors you are posting, so cannot help there.

Comment: So I followed the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729836/update-angular-to-latest/44734137#44734137